# Why can't I run executables in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, permissions

I work with Windows 7 on this machine. But this Windows 7 is protected and I cannot run .exe files on this machine.

How can I make the executables run on this computer?

Note: My account ***doesn't*** have Administrator rights.

Comment: Can you take a look at this and tell me if it fix the issue? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950505

Comment: Mmmmm..I'm not sure though but you can try to open it through Command line but may wanna open it as admin ; open your start menu ... type **cmd** in your search zone..when the cmd icon comes up right click on it and select **run as administrator** ..
After that navigate to your .exe file path and just type FILENAME.exe ..
Good luck

Comment: What happens when you try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not an administrator, ask your administrator for permission to run them. There is most likely a good reason as to why you do not have the ability to run them.

If this is actually your machine and you have forgotten the administrator password or similar, please give more information.

Comment: Good answer. Probably also with Windows 7, he'd need UAC Credentials to run .exe files.

Comment: Who knows, good answer though so +1 from me.